# Guardar PDF ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, pdf, jspdf

quiero generar un pdf de un div en especifico pero no me da todo lo que quiero que imprima. Estoy usando jspdf como libreria. 
Les paso un fragmento de mi codigo

En el aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jspdf.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
         function genPDF() {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
             pdf.addHTML($('#thumbnail'),
                5,
                5,
                function () {
                    pdf.save('div.pdf');
                });
        }
    </script>
```

El div areaImprimir contiene otros div que se llenan de forma dinamica se generan QR, en una pagina caben 21 QR, pero ya no me imprime los demas si quiero que me imprima 60 siempre se corta en 21.

```
  <div id="areaImprimir">
    <div id="PrintQRStudents" runat="server"></div>
         <div id="PrintQRRespuestas" runat="server"></div                
              <div id="PrintQRPuntos" runat="server"></div>
                  </div>
```

Botón:

```
<a href="javascript:genPDF()" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Guardar Folios QR
                      </a>
```

Comment: Necesitarías clarificar un poco, que esperas? en que resulta?